# C# Foreach on an IQueryable<List>

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable, stack-overflow

I'm getting stackoverflow exceptions on the following code...

```
IQueryable<MilestoneList> ml = from MilestoneList d in this.getDB().AsQueryable<MilestoneList>()
                                         where d.Contains((Milestone)toDelete) == true
                                         select d;
                if (ml.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (MilestoneList m in ml)
                    {
                        m.Remove((Milestone)toDelete);
                        this.getDB().Store(m);
                    }
                }
```

My MilestoneList object had IEnumerable and IEnumerator implemented.

But looping through a list of those objects shouldn't be problem I assume.
Anybody has any tips for pushing me in a direction towards a solution?

more info on request.

**update  & Answer :**

The problem seems to be at the Contain function.
It was an embarrassing mistake.. sorry for your lost time..

```
public bool Contains(Milestone m)
    {
        Activate(ActivationPurpose.Read);
        return this._mList.Contains(m);
    }
```

I forgot the to refer to my internal list. So I generaly created an infinite loop.

Comment: Stack overflow means you're calling something that is calling itself. Can you show the stack trace of your exception, and the whole method the above code is from?

Comment: Also, have you tried debugging it and see where it is you're getting the exception? There is nothing inherently wrong with the code you've posted, it has to be the context it is being used in.

Comment: That is the whole method... - An object value is passed to it (toDelete), I retrieve every MilestoneList object from the database (db4o) which contains that object, I check if there are results and loop through every object in the result to perform an action... - The debugger trips over the foreach, the IQueryable doens't give a problem...

Comment: You are getting a stackoverflow on code that should not give a stackoverflow and giving it to stackoverflow :P The problem could be somewhere in the Remove or Store method....

Comment: mmm it's stuck on the ml.Count() method... very strange.. it's the easiest of methods :p

Comment: To start with, remove the call to `ml.Count()`, and just use the code inside the if-statement. The foreach-statement will be skipped if the query returns nothing, so you don't need the if-statement.

Comment: doesn't make a difference... - "{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}" ..

Comment: Ok, have you checked the stack trace? the Call stack window of Visual Studio, anything that would tell you why it is in a stack overflow state?

Comment: Also, are you using lazy loading of some of the references from Milestone outwards, that would contain lazy references back?

Comment: Yeah, the items in MilestoneList are lazy loaded.. - Still looking for the call stack but it doesn't seem to give anything usefull

Comment: for some reason this little piece of code spawns an infinite amount of milestones... - When my milestonelist gets activated, I get the following stackpoint: "> DataEntityTier.dll!DataEntityTier.Utilities.DeletableSupport.Activate(Db4objects.Db4o.Activation.ActivationPurpose purpose = Read) Line 40 + 0xf bytes C#"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update & Answer :

The problem seems to be at the Contain function. It was an embarrassing mistake.. sorry for your lost time..

```
public bool Contains(Milestone m)
    {
        Activate(ActivationPurpose.Read);
        return this._mList.Contains(m);
    }
```

I forgot the to refer to my internal list. So I generaly created an infinite loop.